Excel automatically changes =IMAGE() to =@IMAGE()
When I have an =IMAGE(<url>) formula in Google Sheets and export to Excel file, and then open it with Excel, Excel automatically converts it to =@IMAGE(<url>).
This breaks the formula. I can fix it by simply removing the @ and the image now renders correctly in Excel.
I inspected the .xlsx file before opening it in Excel and I can see that the formula is =IMAGE and not =@IMAGE, so I know that it is not Google Sheets that adds the @.
How do I prevent Excel from adding this @?

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Are you using Excel for Windows, for Mac or Online?

Windows with excel for office 365
